# i want Like operator to perform differently or any alternative

Tags: mysql

I am using this query to search the results

```
select #__community_mt_links.id,#__community_cfvalues.link_id
from #__community_mt_links inner join
     #__community_cfvalues on #__community_mt_links.id=#__community_cfvalues.link_id 
where #__community_mt_links.link_name LIKE '%burhani bag%' or
      #__community_mt_links.address LIKE '%burhani bag%' or
      #__community_mt_links.city LIKE '%burhani bag%' or
      #__community_mt_links.state LIKE '%burhani bag%' or
      #__community_mt_links.country LIKE '%burhani bag%' or
      #__community_mt_links.link_desc LIKE '%burhani bag%' or
      #__community_cfvalues.value LIKE '%burhani bag%'
```

and 1000 result will appear in the above query but when i write the same query for 
keyword "burhani bags" i am adding 's' in the keyword then

```
select #__community_mt_links.id,#__community_cfvalues.link_id
from #__community_mt_links inner join
     #__community_cfvalues on #__community_mt_links.id=#__community_cfvalues.link_id
where #__community_mt_links.link_name LIKE '%burhani bags%' or
      #__community_mt_links.address LIKE '%burhani bags%' or
      #__community_mt_links.city LIKE '%burhani bags%' or
      #__community_mt_links.state LIKE '%burhani bags%' or
      #__community_mt_links.country LIKE '%burhani bags%' or
      #__community_mt_links.link_desc LIKE '%burhani bags%' or 
      #__community_cfvalues.value LIKE '%burhani bags%'
```

no result will appear . I can solve it by putting wild card  character but I need permanent solution for any case like above.

I mean any word that contain something like my keyword.

I am using php as front end.

can you suggest me some function or alternative for this case.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The problem is that the user can search with the pluralized name, but you only save the data in singular?

Comment: You could use `SOUNDEX` or such: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_soundex

Comment: if as @Marcus suggested, what language are you using (C#/Java/etc..) to access your SQL?

Comment: i am using php as front end

Comment: I've reformatted so that the queries can be seen without scrolling. On a side note, you might want to look into using aliases - they'd let you introduce a short name for each table rather than having to repeat its full name everywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `SOUNDS LIKE` (or SOUNDEX) like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM community_links C
WHERE C.link_name SOUNDS LIKE '%burhani bags%'
```

This is only a simplified answer in relation to your actual table structure.

See my [Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/81473/1)

A resource also [here](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-sounds_like-function.php)